# how to read multiple .gz files in a particular directory in python without unzipping them

Tags: python, zip, unzip

I have a folder /var/tmp in my linux directory where i have multiple .gz files in the below mentioned format (name_yyyymmddhhmmss.gz).

aakashdeep_20181120080005.gz
aakashdeep_20181120080025.gz
kalpana_20181119080005.gz
aakashdeep_20181120080025.gz

Now i want to open all the gz files with format as name_20181120*.gz without unzipping them and read the content out of them.

i have written a simple code

## !/usr/bin/python

import gzip

output = gzip.open('/var/tmp/Aakashdeep/aakashdeep_20181120080002.gz','r')

for line in output:
    print (line)

and the same is giving me the output as expected, but i want to open all the files like below
output = gzip.open('/var/tmp/Aakashdeep/aakashdeep_20181120*.gz','r')

Can anyone suggest me the way for this.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob.glob` to obtain a list of files to process, then open each with `gzip.open`, do something with its contents, and move on to the next. Outline (untested):

```
import glob
import gzip

ZIPFILES='/var/tmp/Aakashdeep/aakashdeep_20181120*.gz'

filelist = glob.glob(ZIPFILES)
for gzfile in filelist:
    # print("#Starting " + gzfile)  #if you want to know which file is being processed  
    with gzip.open( gzfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
             print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel. The code you mentioned above, worked for me.

Comment: The pattern (`for filename in glob.glob(...)`  then `with`) is one that I've used hundreds of times, but oddly never with `gzip`. It's the Python equivalent of most bash commands with a `-r` recusive option. BTW `for gzfile in sorted(filelist)` may be an easy cosmetic  improvement, though the sort order isn't always exactly what you want)